# Open Browser with Url and exit App in Background in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to develop an App that open the default Browser with an Url and then the App exits. I am able to open the Url, but when I exit the App, the Browser exits too.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let application = UIApplication.shared
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.de")! 'Url is of course a different one'
    
    if application.canOpenURL(url){
        application.open(url)
    }
}
```

What do I wrong.
It is supposed to be just a shortcut on the Home Screen to a Website. Downloadable in the App Store.

Comment: Apple will not approve an App Store app that is just a link to a website.

Comment: You can simply "Add to home" link in your website, no need to build an app just for a website shortcut.

Comment: I am new to iOS so I thought it could be possible. But if the App Store will not even approve it, then it is nonsense to develop such an App.
Thanks to you

Comment: This is already implemented with Shortcuts app - https://help.dozuki.com/Guide/How+to+Create+a+Safari+Shortcut+(iOS+13)/6739

Answer (score 1):

Please read https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ 4.2  Apple says.

> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it
> beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful,
> unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store

So even you send it to Appstore to your app. Apple has to reject it